# Passing 2D int array from one function to another in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

For example, I have two functions: first one gets height and width from main() and reads 2D int array

```
int read_price (int height, int width) { 
  int i, j;
  int array[height][width];

  printf("Enter your values:\n");

  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &array[i][j]); 
    }
  }
}
```

Second function gets values from the first and prints it.

```
void print_array () {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
      printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

And - the question! How should I call second function inside the first (with which arguments)? And which arguments should I write beetween brackets in the name of second function.

I tried to call in this (and some another) way(s), but I get errors.

```
print_array (array[height][width]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C99 you can use array with a variable length. In your case the definition of the function print_array will look like:

```
void print_array (int height, int width, int array[height][width]) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

and you will call it as:

```
print_array(height, width, array);
```

Because in C you are not sending arrays, just pointers, the previous definition is equal to a definition when you send a pointer (to an array of `width` integers) which you can define as:

```
void print_array (int height, int width, int (*array)[width]) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how should I pass args from the first function?
`print_array(height, width, array[][]);` ?
It throws error

Comment: It seems to be a last question. I edited it, like it is in your answer, but firstly I similarly get errors. Then I tried to compile it in the terminal with gcc, but as .c file. It worked. Before that I compiled my code in Clion as .cpp. Is it normal?

Comment: I think that variable length arrays are not part of C++.